# GitHub Actions for react native with multiple targets

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am building an automated pipeline with GitHub actions for my react native app, I have one app with two targets and my .yml file looks like below, and it fails at xcodebuild step.

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy iOS
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'build/actions-test'
jobs:
  build-ios:
    runs-on: macos-12 #Monterey
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Node.js 16.17.1
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.17.1
          cache: 'yarn'

      - name: Install Node modules
        run: yarn

      - name: Setup Ruby (bundle)
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.7.4
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Restore Pods cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            ios/Pods
            ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
            ~/.cocoapods
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pods-${{ hashFiles('ios/Podfile.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pods-
      - name: Install pod dependencies
        run: cd ios && pod install && cd ..
      - name: Clean Xcode Build
        run: |
          cd ios
          xcodebuild clean -workspace HemeNew.xcworkspace -scheme 'HemeNew 1'

      - name: Build iOS (Release)
        uses: yukiarrr/ios-build-action@v1.5.0
        with:
          project-path: ios/HemeNew.xcodeproj
          p12-base64: ${{ secrets.IOS_P12_BASE64 }}
          mobileprovision-base64: ${{ secrets.IOS_MOBILE_PROVISION_BASE64 }}
          code-signing-identity: 'Apple Distribution'
          certificate-password: ${{ secrets.IOS_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD }}
          team-id: ${{ secrets.IOS_TEAM_ID }}
          workspace-path: ios/HemeNew.xcworkspace
          output-path: 'HemeNew.ipa'
          scheme: 'HemeNew 1'

      - name: Upload build
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: 'HemeNew.ipa'
          path: 'HemeNew.ipa'
```

The steps till pod installation goes well, but when the xcode build step is executed, it is giving an error staging that there are multiple targets and the provisioning profile I am using is matching the main target, but its not matching the other target.
I tried

- Giving the same bundle id to the other target, but it gave an error stating that there are multiple targets with same bundle id,
- I also tried by giving different bundle id, but it gave error that the provisioning profile I am using is not matching the other target

How do I achieve the successful build with both targets (same bundleid / different bundleid)?